# set column values in octave dataframe

Tags: matlab, dataframe, octave

I have two sets of data as follows;

```
file a:
 1476356687
 1476356689
 1476356690

file b:
 "2016-10-13 12:04:47.706193",1000,516130
 "2016-10-13 12:04:49.225305",2000,516130
 "2016-10-13 12:04:50.439240",3000,516130

 new_col=dataframe("file_a")
 df=dataframe("file_b")


>> size(new_col)
ans =

   3     1

>> size(df)
ans =

   3     3

>> new_col(1:3,:)
ans = dataframe with 3 rows and 1 columns
_1    new_col
Nr     double
 1 1476356687
 2 1476356689
 3 1476356690
>> df(1:3,:)
ans = dataframe with 3 rows and 3 columns
Src: import_nbu_op
_1                         X1     X2     X3
Nr                       char double double
 1 2016-10-13 12:04:47.706193   1000 516130
 2 2016-10-13 12:04:49.225305   2000 516130
 3 2016-10-13 12:04:50.439240   3000 516130
```

I am trying to either set column 1 of df to be new_col, or construct a new dataframe of new_col and columns 2:end of df

I have tried a bunch of things, but can't figure out the magic incantation to get it to work.... coming from something like python, this is driving be bonkers ;)

I have tried,

```
>> df=dataframe(new_col,df)
error: Concatenating dataframes: use cat instead
error: called from
    dataframe at line 568 column 5
>> df=cat(new_col,df)
error: Incorrect call to cat
error: called from
    cat at line 197 column 7
>> df=cat(1,new_col,df)
error: Different number of columns in dataframes
error: called from
    cat at line 50 column 11
>> df=cat(2,new_col,df)
df(1): out of bound 0
error: called from
    display at line 66 column 7
>> df=cat(0,new_col,df)
error: Incorrect call to cat
error: called from
    cat at line 197 column 7
    display at line 66 column 7
>> cat(2,1,new_col,df)
error: Different number of rows in dataframes
error: called from
    cat at line 109 column 11
>> cat(2,2,new_col,df)
error: Different number of rows in dataframes
error: called from
    cat at line 109 column 11
>> horzcat(new_col,df)
error: df(2): out of bound 1
error: called from
    display at line 66 column 7
>> df(:,1)=new_col
error: cast: TYPE must be a string
error: called from
    cast at line 67 column 5
    df_matassign at line 452 column 31
    subsasgn at line 217 column 10
>> dataframe(df,new_col)
error: Concatenating dataframes: use cat instead
error: called from
    dataframe at line 568 column 5
```

Then, Eureka I thought! Almost there! at least I can add the col to the frame now...

```
>> dataframe(df,new_col.array(:,:))
ans = dataframe with 3 rows and 4 columns
Src: import_nbu_op
 _1                         X1     X2     X3          X
 Nr                       char double double     double
  1 2016-10-13 12:04:47.706193   1000 516130 1476356687
  2 2016-10-13 12:04:49.225305   2000 516130 1476356689
  3 2016-10-13 12:04:50.439240   3000 516130 1476356690
```

Excellent. So I just need to swap df and new_col around to create the frame  I (almost) want! just a couple of steps away :)

```
>> dataframe(new_col.array(:,:),df)
error: Concatenating dataframes: use cat instead
error: called from
    dataframe at line 568 column 5
```

Argh! How the what why?

```
>> cat(1,new_col,df(:,2:end))
error: Different number of columns in dataframes
error: called from
    cat at line 50 column 11
>> cat(2,new_col,df(:,2:end))
error: df(2): out of bound 1
error: called from
    display at line 66 column 7
>> horzcat(new_col,df(:,2:end))
error: df(2): out of bound 1
```

Help! - I've tried more permutations of various things than this, but it all ends the same way :(

Comment: I want to repeat: You really should try to create a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Some code which create the dataframe, best without any external dependencies on files which someone can copy and paste. Without this you ask us to do the daunting work to create some sample data which might mimic your problem.

Comment: Sure, I can copy-paste in some rows from the datasets I am using;  you did mention last time - and I thought giving clear examples of the datasets as at the start of this post would be enough.  But no problem, I'll add in some copy-pasta people can grab to recreate the problem.

Comment: Added in example files and code on how the dataframes were created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work using its `.cell` property as opposed to `.array` you tried:

```
>> concatenated = dataframe(cat(2, new_col.cell, df.cell))
concatenated = dataframe with 3 rows and 7 columns                              
_1 unnamed          X unnamed1 unnamed2                         X1     X2     X3
Nr    char     double   double     char                       char double double
 1         1.4764e+09        1          2016-10-13 12:04:47.706193   1000 516130
 2         1.4764e+09        2          2016-10-13 12:04:49.225305   2000 516130
 3         1.4764e+09        3          2016-10-13 12:04:50.439240   3000 516130
```

However, this results in columns 1,3 and 4 as artefacts (presumably 1 and 4 is from an empty space character, and 3 is the previous 'ascending index' numbers). So I had to remove these to get my dataframe:

```
>> concatenated(:,[1,3,4]) = []
concatenated = dataframe with 3 rows and 4 columns    
_1          X                         X1     X2     X3
Nr     double                       char double double
 1 1.4764e+09 2016-10-13 12:04:47.706193   1000 516130
 2 1.4764e+09 2016-10-13 12:04:49.225305   2000 516130
 3 1.4764e+09 2016-10-13 12:04:50.439240   3000 516130
```

I agree though, this package does seem pretty broken.

PS. The `dataframe` pkg is specific to octave. This question is not matlab-related. Matlab offers `dataset` and `table` classes (and I've also seen a `datamatrix` class, and a `dataframe` fileexchange one).

Comment: Thanks. That works fine. I think I either need to find a better dataframe package, or stick will the types already in octave.

Comment: Yes, for now I agree. I think a 'dataframe' class containing just the functionality you need would be fairly straightforward to implement. :)

Comment: (having said that, if you agree this is the correct answer for your particular conundrum, feel free to accept it and bring some joy into my dull, sad little life :p )